# How to make a discord.js bot dm all members in my server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot DM all people (not just new members), and i have no clue how i would go about doing this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Async context (within async function), 'message' being the command message.

const members = message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).array(); // Filter out bots.

let undelivered = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {  // Using an array and a for loop rather than
  const member = members[i];                // Collection.forEach() due to the fact that
  await member.send('Hello there.')         // the latter will move onto the proceeding
    .catch(() => undelivered++);            // code before waiting for the promises to
}                                           // fulfill. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787

message.channel.send(`Messages sent. ${undelivered} members couldn't receive it.`)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: The code above must be within an async function (declared as `async function(...) {` or `async (...) => {`).

Comment: The callback must be async. That line should look like this: `bot.on('ready', async () => {`. You'll also need to change `message.guild` to the guild you want to use (i.e. `client.guilds.get('id')`).

Comment: is there a way without id

Comment: You could use [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) to search for a guild with a certain property, i.e. `client.guilds.find(g => g.name === 'test')`.

Comment: You can use `message.guild.members.filter(...).forEach(async member => { // code })` instead of the for loop

Comment: As explained in the comment, `forEach()` won't wait for promises to fulfill, and will therefore send the message after the loop immediately. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787